# Changing color of row in tableview on button click

Tags: javafx

I want to permanently change color of selected row in tableview after button clicked.

I have button and I set it on action, so when button is clicked I want to change color of selected row in tableview.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is not clear how you'd want this implemented. But one way would be to override the `RowFactory` and change the style based on some value in your model. Again, without code, impossible to tell you for sure.

Comment: You can get the selected row and set a style. So I guess it is simple to answer. But please give some code of yours for a more concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in my table, in my TableModel I have the field color, which is maintained but not displayed. Colors are set like so:

```
            myTable.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(MyTableRow row, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(row, empty);
                if(row==null) {
                    setStyle("");
                } else if (row.getColor().equals("Grey")) {
                    setStyle(Theme.REPORT_THEME_GREY);
                } else if (row.getColor().equals("Yellow")) {
                    setStyle(Theme.REPORT_THEME_YELLOW);
                } else if (row.getColor().equals("Orange")) {
                    setStyle(Theme.REPORT_THEME_ORANGE);
                } else if (row.getColor().equals("Blue")) {
                    setStyle(Theme.REPORT_THEME_BLUE);
                } else if (row.getColor().equals("Mauve")) {
                    setStyle(Theme.REPORT_THEME_PURPLE);
                } else if (row.getColor().equals("Peach")) {
                    setStyle(Theme.REPORT_THEME_PEACH);
                } else if (row.getColor().equals("White")) {
                    setStyle(Theme.REPORT_THEME_WHITE);
                } else if (row.getColor().equals("Red")) {
                    setStyle(Theme.REPORT_THEME_RED);
                } else if (row.getColor().equals("Green")) {
                    setStyle(Theme.REPORT_THEME_GREEN);
                } else {
                    setStyle("");
                }
            }
        });
```

Colors and styles would of course be altered to suite.

My version is not tied to a button, but it should be a simple matter of calling the setColor(Color) method on your model for the selected row and redrawing the table.